# How Can I add additional functions to Visual Studio's Server Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in

I am trying to write simple Visual Studio Add-In for code generation. In my solution explorer window there is a database connection an I want to get table names from this active connection.How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this using DDEX Designer. For more information you can see example from [Get data sources, data providers and data connections from a Visual Studio](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2007/MZ2007018.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[Example](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms/topic53084.aspx)

This looks to be what you need.